# Hotfixes: Are they made off of master or develop?

Tags: git, git-flow

My team recently starting using Git Flow.  We start all `feature` branches off of `develop` and follow the rest of the recommended git flow protocol.  A bug made it in `master` and now I want to create hotfix for it.  Would I create the hotfix branch from master or would I follow the same protocol as creating feature branches and make it off of develop?

Comment: Create the ‘hotfix’ branch off of master - that will avoid polluting master with develop changes not yet merged up (and likely unrelated to the fix). Merge the fix into master *and* develop (merging master to develop after the hotfix has been supplied is often also sufficient, see organization process) so that the changes are applied consistently and develop can be cleanly merged forward into master the next time such is done.

Comment: A "hotfix" is by definition off of master. If it's off of develop, it is by definition a feature branch. You cannot have a hotfix off of develop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `hotfix` and `bugfix` in your case.

Create `hotfix` from `master`, and do some fixes. After that, merge it into master and also develop.
(merging also to develop is mandatory)
And if you need, you can use cherrypick from `develop` branch to `hotfix` branch.
(use this when fixes are already in `develop` or other `feature` branch)

If you think it is not urgent and you want to fix this on next release, but this is not some new feature, then you can use `bugfix` branch, instead of creating new `feature` branch.
(create `bugfix` branch from `develop` -> do some fixes -> merge to `develop`)